# How Many Paths? Impassable Boulder.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We want to count step-by-step paths between points with integer coordinates. Only
two kinds of steps are allowed: a right-step which increments the $x$ coordinate by $1$ and an up-step which increments the $y$ coordinate by $1$.

(i) How many paths are there from point $(0,0)$ to point $(10,10)$?
(ii) How many paths are there if there is an impassable boulder sitting at point $(5,6)$?
(iii) How many paths are there if there are impassable boulders sitting at points $(2,3)$ and $(6,8)$?

---

My solution:

(i) $\binom{20}{10}$

(ii) $\binom{20}{10} - \binom{11}{6}\binom{9}{4}$

(iii) $\binom{20}{10} - \binom{5}{3}\binom{15}{107} - \binom{14}{8}\binom{6}{2} + \binom{5}{3} \binom{9}{5} \binom{6}{2}$

Is my attempt correct **NOW**?

Answer (score 3):

The first two are fine, though the second would be improved by the addition of a comment explaining that you’re subtracting the paths through the point occupied by the boulder. The third isn’t quite right, because you’ve subtracted **twice** the paths that go through both boulders. You need to add those back in. Judging from what you’ve done so far, I suspect that you can do this, but if not, please ask.

**Added:** The updated version looks fine.

Comment: ok would adding (5 choose 3)(9 choose 5)(6 choose 2) to (iii) make it right

Comment: @reddoor: That looks right. The general principle involved here is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).